# QT - Existing slot is not visible from mainwidow.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I need to do some heavy calculations, so I decided to move it to worker thread to avoid GUI freeze. Lets assume that I have two files: `mainwindow.cpp` and `calc.cpp`. Both have header files obliviously. Some user input is gathered from GUI, when user press a button, the calculation starts. A snippet here:

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "calc.h"
Va = ui->lineEdit_Va->text().toDouble();
Vb = ui->lineEdit_Vb->text().toDouble();
//Progress bar definition
sender = new calc();
connect(sender, SIGNAL( inprogress(int) ), ui->progressBar, SLOT( setValue(int) ) );
//Calculation begins here
QThread* newThread = new QThread();
sender->moveToThread(newThread);
connect( newThread, SIGNAL(started()), sender, SLOT(transfer(Va, Vb)));
newThread->start();
```

`calc.h`

```
class calc : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    calc(QObject *parent=0);
public slots:
    void transfer(double Va, double Vb);
signals:
    void inprogress(int progr);
};
```

While progress bar connection works totally fine, the `connect( newThread, SIGNAL(started()), sender, SLOT(transfer(Va, Vb)));` seems to be invisible for qt creator. It ends with the error:

> QObject::connect: No such slot calc::transfer(Va, Vb) in ../my-directory/mainwindow.cpp

I thought it may be releated to old moc files, however I tried cleaning build, changing working directory, even manually deleting of moc files and nothing changed. So the question is, why this slot is invisible from mainwindow.cpp, despite it is set as public?

Comment: Just a piece of general advice. Stay away from the string based signal/slot connections (the ones using the `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros), and instead prefer the new style connections using compile-time-checked pointer-to-member-function syntax. They are safer and faster.

Comment: You need to specify the *type* names not the formal parameter names in the `SLOT` spec.  So `SLOT(transfer(double, double))`.  Note that if you follow the advise of @JesperJuhl this would almost certainly have been flagged by the compiler.

Comment: Maybe I miss something in slot concept but if i do so: `connect( newThread, &NewThread::started, sender, &Sender::transfer);` How would I specif arguments to be transfered with slot?

Comment: Where are `Va` and `Vb` ? Does calc have access to them? You can't pass parameters like you are doing.

Comment: @drescherjm - Edited first post, to include Va and Vb definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
connect(newThread, &QThread::started,
        [=]() { sender->transfer(Va, Vb); });
```

Comment: Seems to makes a sens. However what is a declaration of  `NewThread`? It ends with: `'NewThread' has not been declared connect(newThread, &NewThread::started,`

Comment: Should be `QThread`. I copy/pasted blindly from a comment. Edited.

Comment: It works. The codes compile and calculation follow. However I don't understand this syntax `[=]() { sender->transfer(Va, Vb); });`. Just out of competition, it is not intuitive for me.

Comment: @Karls, its c++ Lambda